# Error when parsing html using php simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm new to php `simple_html_dom.php`
I'm trying parse a small html page. But I'm getting an error.
`Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\result\do.php on line 8`

My php code is here :
`

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('C:\xampp\htdocs\result\www.html');
$tableData = array();
$table = $html->find('table');      
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td.text') as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }       
    $tableData[] = $rowData;
}
echo "Result :<br/>";
foreach($tableData as $test)
    echo "-".$test[0]."-".$test[1]."-".$test[2]."-".$test[3]."-".$test[4]."<br/>";
```

?>` 

and my html page is here (www.html):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width=250>Subject</td>
    <td width=60 align=center>External </td>
    <td width=60 align=center>Internal</td>
    <td align=center width=60>Total</td>
    <td align=center width=60>Result</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=250><i>Analog Communication (06EC53)</i></td>
    <td width=60 align=center>0</td>
    <td width=60 align=center>17</td>
    <td width=60 align=center>17</td>
    <td width=60 align=center><b>A</b>
</td>
```

I want to know why I'm getting this error and how can I solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding html and body tags around that ? I believe the library requires it.

it should be `<html><body> .... </body></html>`

Comment: I have already tried that but its not working and I think that the library doesn't required full html page.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you tried to call `find()` on something that was empty, probably because that something was the result of another call to `find()` that didn't actually find anything. The likely culprit here is `$table` because you never bother checking that `$html->find('table')` actually succeeds before going ahead and trying to use the result.